# Magento2 - extend Category API save functionality

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am trying to extend the save() functionality on magento2, when it handles an Catalog / Category API call. I do not want to extend any events, as I figure they're being handled globally which is not what I want to achieve.

Rather, I want to have my module handle the PUT calls on `rest/all/V1/categories/<id>` and apply my custom business logic there.

Question: how can I achieve this? I figure that I want to add a type definition to my `di.xml` that defines my CategoryInterface, but I am having a hard time to identify how to inject only to the API interface.

Answer (score 0):

di.xml and events.xml can be applied only to a specific area. If you want to trigger only on api calls you just need to create events.xml or di.xml in the specific area in your etc folder. For example in the image below the di.xml is only going to be applied for rest and soap api calls.

[image]